# Flash CS6 - 2 Questions?

Tags: flash, adobe

Question 1 - I have a flash swf file and I want to display it in the browser in full mode meaning it should fit the browser, I have tried adding

```
fscommand("fullscreen", "true");
```

in the first frame of a lyaer but it does not work.

Question 2 - How to redirect to another page at the end of the swf movie, I have tried adding :

```
stop();

navigateToURL( new URLRequest("*www.microsoft.com*"), "_self");
```

in the last frame but it does not work.

Thank you very very much for your assitance !!
Tonya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Q-1 :

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="your.swf" width="100%" height="100%">
```

For Q-2 :

```
var url:String = "http://www.microsoft.com"
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
navigateToURL(urlRequest, "_self");
```